# Rails 6 app with stimulus reflex deployment on Heroku problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, stimulus-reflex

I deploy my Rails 6 app (with stimulus-relflex) on Heroku. Everything work find including my jQuery and JS but anything related to stimulus-relfex dont work? Everything work fine on my local dev machine. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you still have this problem? If you check Heroku logs, do you see any messages related to Stimulus Reflex that might reveal a problem?

Comment: Hard to help you, with so little information. Is caching set up correctly? As stimulus reflex relies on having caching available.

Answer (score 1):

You give very little information, but my first guess would be to check the `config/cable.yml`. It is misleading, but `ActionCable` "just works" in development, while in production mode one has to configure a pubsub queueing system. The default is set to "redis", which is a (payable?) add-on on heroku, and if you already use redis, it has to be configured/linked correctly in the `cable.yml`.

A very simple solution is to use postgresql as the pubsub queue, which you are probably already using (on heroku), and is as simple as writing

```
 production:
   adapter: postgresql
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the redis addon on heroku to your application maybe that works..